# Router.url() returning undefined in Email.send()

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am trying to construct an email for some users.  Code is running server-side.  In the email I would like to have a link for the users to click on, but I am not having much luck.

I am trying to use `Router.url()` to set the `href` of an anchor.  I can do `console.log()` and see the Router object is at least defined, but the link ends up being strange.

The code looks like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  sendSubmissionEmail: function(responseId) {
    // Let other method calls from the same client start running,
    // without waiting for the email sending to complete.
    this.unblock();

    var formResponse = FormResponses.findOne({_id: responseId});
    var toEmails = [];
    _.each(Roles.getUsersInRole('ADMIN').fetch(), function(user) {
      if (user.profile && user.profile.receivesResponseEmails) {
        var email = _.findWhere(user.emails, {verified: true});
        if (!email) {
          console.log('No verified email address was found for ' + user.username + '. Using unverified email instead.');
          email = _.first(user.emails);
        }
        if (email) {
          toEmails.push(email.address);
        }
      }
    });

    if (toEmails && toEmails.length > 0) {
      console.log('Sending an email to the following Admins: ' + toEmails);
      console.log('Router: ', Router);
      Email.send({
        from: 'noreply@strataconsulting.us',
        to: toEmails,
        subject: 'Form Response for Form "' + formResponse.form_title + '" Ready For Approval',
        html: '<p>Form Response for Form <a href="' + Router.url('editResponse', formResponse.id) + '">' + formResponse.formTitle + '</a> is now ready for your approval.</p>'
      });
    }
  }
});
```

And the resulting email:

```
====== BEGIN MAIL #0 ======
MIME-Version: 1.0
From: noreply@strataconsulting.us
To: testuser4@codechimp.net
Subject: Form Response for Form "undefined" Ready For Approval
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

<p>Form Response for Form <a href=3D"undefined">Test Form One</a> is now ready for your approval.</p>
====== END MAIL #0 ======
```

First, there is a strange "3D" appearing prior to the first " of the href, then the return or Router.url() is always `undefined`.  Just to make sure the call was right, I simulated it in Chrome's dev tools console by doing the following:

```
var fr = FormResponses.findOne({_id: '1234567890'});
Router.url('editResponse', fr);
```

As expected this spits out the full URL path to my editResponse route with the correct ID set.  Is Router.url() a client-only call?  If so, how do I get the URL to a route server-side?  All routes are defined for both client and server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
var fr = FormResponses.findOne({_id: '1234567890'});
Router.url('editResponse', fr);
```

You're passing the result of the Find as a parameter. It'll look like

{ _id: ..., otherStuff: ...}

But in your code you're not passing an object, you're just passing a string:

```
Router.url('editResponse', formResponse.id)
```

That explains the "undefined".

The 3D is very odd.

Comment: I did try it by passing the whole object as well, but I still get the weird "3D" and the undefined.  I also noticed an error was getting spit out:  `(STDERR) You called Router.url for a route named "editResponse" but that route doesn't seem to exist. Are you sure you created it?`, but there is a route called 'editResponse'.

Comment: Are you defining the routes in part of the code base that's used by both the client and server?

Comment: Crap, that was the problem.  I had the file in a place that should have been picked up, but way at the top I had `if (Meteor.isClient) {` defined around the whole file.  Man I feel stupid now.  I have been staring at this for several days going "WTF!  This should be working!".  I am still getting the weird "3D" in the output, but since I am still testing locally and emails are being simulated I can't tell if that's just some artifact in the log message or if it will actually be in the final email.

Comment: 3D is the uri encoding for the = character. Not sure you should be seeing it there though.

Comment: Yeah, I'd expect it would be something like `&#3D;` or whatever the traditional HTML escaping format is.  Also, not sure why it has the 3D and the = right after.  Again, may just be a logging thing.  I will find out if it comes out as part of the actual email when I get the code into Prod.